# Custom post and category template pagination problem

Tags: categories, pagination

I have a category template which holds a query to custom post with a category. The strange thing is when the pagination loads it displays how many pages we have. But when I click on the second page of the pagination it gives me a 404 page.

If I make the query only to fetch the custom post or to fetch the category it works fine. After I have refresh the query with the test for the custom post and the category it works fine. Here is the code of the category template:

```
<div id="conteiner-first-vision">
<section id="inner-pad">
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type' =>  'awards-pub',
    'cat'=>6,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order'=>'DESC'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
//wp_query->query('showposts=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
$i=1;
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() )
{
    $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
<article class="article-first-vision <?= ($i==2)?'mar':'' ?>" >
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail('menu-pub'); ?>
  </a>
  <?php
}; ?>
  <h2>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h2>
  <div class="article-description">
    <?= truncateHtml(get_the_content()); ?>
  </div>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="bottom:0; right:0;" class="pa"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/link-articles.png"></a> </article>
<?php
if($i==3){$i=0;}
$i++;
}
?>
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="pagination-conteiner">
<?php
    get_template_part('pagination');
?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

And this is the pagination:

```
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('«'),
    'next_text'    => __('»'),
));
```

And this is the custom post:

```
 register_post_type('awards-pub', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Awards', 'awardspub'), // Rename these to suit
        'singular_name' => __('Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'add_new' => __('Add Awards', 'awardspub'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add Awards  Post', 'awardspub'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'awardspub'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'new_item' => __('New Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'view' => __('View Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'view_item' => __('View Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Awards Post', 'awardspub'),
        'not_found' => __('No Awards Posts found', 'awardspub'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Awards Posts found in Trash', 'awardspub')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'comments',
        'thumbnail'
    ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
    'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'post_tag',
        'category'
    ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
));
```

And to add the category to the custom post:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'awards-pub');
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'awards-pub');
```

Comment: I have found that it start to work if i go to the posts and make more then the post_per_page post with that category.

Comment: Hi here is the andswer to my question:

    add_action( 'parse_query','changept' );
    function changept() {
 if( is_category() && !is_admin() )
  set_query_var( 'post_type',  array( 'menu-pub', 'new-pub', 'read-pub', 'awards-pub', 'live-pub','post' ));
 return;
    }